# Summing a number of matrices a number of times

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I wrote a Matlab code below which is suppose to solve a system of equations:

```
A(n)U(n)=U(n-1)*(1-Walpha(2))+ Walpha(2)*U(0)+SUM((Walpha(j)-Walpha(j+1))*U(n-j));
```

The code below is running, but, i suspect it is only returning WU(n) at the last j step, but it is suppose to calculate and save the values at each j step and then add these values together for each n step and save the result in WU.

```
U=cell(N,1);
RHS=cell(N,1);
WU=cell(N,1);
RHS{1}=Um0;
U{1}=U1;
WU{1}=zeros(M-1,1);
for n=2:N-1;
for j=1:n-1;
   WU{n}=(Walpha(j)-Walpha(j+1))*U{n-j};                                            
end
RHS{n}=(1-Walpha(2)).*U{n-1}+Walpha(n).*U0+ WU{n}-UU{n};
U{n}=inv(A{n})*RHS{n};                                                       
end
```

Can somebody please explain as to how i should re-write my codes such that the summation part in the system is evaluated correctly.

Comment: How is this a system of linear equations? Is `A{n}` supposed to be a matrix for every `n`? You should provide the information what all those variables are (matrix/vector/cell of matrices/cell of vectors/what dimensions?)

Comment: Hi knedlsepp, sorry for the typo. Its not linear equations but non-linear.. A{n} is an M-1 by M-1 tri-diagonal matrix for every n. WU{n}, RHS{n} and U{n} are column vectors for each n. I wrote them a cells of matrices so that for each n the results is stored.

Comment: Walpha(J) is a scalar., Um0 and U1 are already known from n=1..